# vue filtering list on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a some simple vue project: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-keyboard-test-fv4yx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

There are `input` field, virtual keyboard and some list with `id`.

When clicking on the corresponding numbers (virtual keyboard), the corresponding numbers should be displayed in the `input` field, and `item` with the corresponding set (`id` code) should be displayed in the list.

**Code:**

```
<template>
<ul class="show">
      <li v-bind:key="i" v-for="i in 4" :class="{on: pinLength>=i}"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="key">
      <li>
        <span v-on:click="typePin(1)">1</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span v-on:click="typePin(2)">2</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span v-on:keyup.51="typeNum(3)">3</span>
      </li> ...
    </ul>

    <ul class="items">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in filterItems" v-bind:key="index">
        {{item.name}}
        <br>
        {{item.id}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloKey",
  data() {
    return {
      input: "",
      pin: "",
      items: [
        {
          name: "Item 1",
          id: 12345
        }, ...
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    typePin(num) {
      if (this.pin.length < 4) {
        this.pin = this.pin.concat(num);
        this.input = this.pin;
      }
    },
    clearPin() {
      this.pin = "";
    },
    clearCode() {
      this.code = "";
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.pin = "";
  },
  computed: {
    pinLength() {
      return this.pin.length;
    },
    filterItems() {
      return this.items.filter(item => {
        console.log(this.input);
        return item.id;
        //return item.id.includes(this.input);
        //return item.id.match(this.input);
      });
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

I try: `return item.id.includes(this.input);` or `return item.id.match(this.input);,` but have error:

> item.id.includes is not a function"

**Question:** how i can filter the list by `id` by clicking on the "virtual" keyboard and entering into the form field?

Comment: `includes` is a method of Array or String ... what type is item.id?

Comment: so you want to know if an item's **numeric**  `id` includes the value in this.input?

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes, i want to know if an item's numeric `id` includes the value in `this.input` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regexp `test` methd as follows

```
filterItems() {
  var re = new regExp(this.input);
  return this.items.filter(item => re.test(item.id));
}
```

Comment: thank you ... But just now I realized that I need a sequence match like here https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/JjovzVp

Comment: I messed up the types number and string! Thank you!